# Hacer algo cuando SetInterval canvie Slide

Tags: javascript, slider, setinterval

Lo primero (y perdonad que sea borde y directo) no me ralleis con tonterias de si he posteado bien, de si la pregunta está mal formulada o con faltas de ortografia. **Si me podeis ayudar bien, si no...pues no** Porqué para dos consultas que he hecho...todo el mundo critica y nadie ayuda. Y si me echan por éste comentario, pues me voy a otro foro con gente menos sobervia y mas solidaria.

Voy al grano.
Estoy haciendo un test con diapos (slideShow style) y tengo diapos con timer X, otra con timer Y, y otras sin timer. Obviamente hay respuestas correctas y otras incorrectas.

Si hay 3 respuestas incorrectas seguidas, el test termina. Cuando usuario marca 3 incorrecta seguidas obviamente finaliza. 
Lo que no consigo solucionar es que cuando el intervalo de tiempo finalize, es decir el usuario no ha repondido, lo cuente como respuesta incorrecta.

Como necesito tambien contar lo que se tarda en responder, he puesto una función para ello.
Entonces estoy tratando de hacer:

Si tiempo transcurrido es igual al intervalo de tiempo --> incorrectas++;

Aquí va el JS completo:

```
// JavaScript Document

//VARIABLES GLOBALS
//vars control repsostes
var si = 0; //repsostes correctes
var no = 0; // respostes incorrectes necessari per si 3 incorrectes seguide = fi test
var i= 0;
//vars de control intervals de temps
var init; //inici temps 
var finit; //fi temps
var diferenciaT; // diferencia temps
var t= 0; // aquí hi guardarem els intervals de temps que volem modificar
var array_diferenciaT =[]; // guardem els intervals de temps transcorreguts "Diapo + interval transcorregut"

var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides"); // agafem els divs i els posem a una var
var slideIndex = -1; // control del lenght de slides
var repeater; // var que servira per llençar funció SETINTERVAL de forma dinamica (parar-la, modificar-ne valors, etc.)



//imprimir en pantalla SLIDEINDEX PER MANTENIR RELACIO -->SLIDEINDEX a Nº RESPOSTA TEST //
function controlIndex(){
    var textIndex = slideIndex;
    document.getElementById('slideIndSpan').innerHTML = "Index: " +textIndex;

}

// FUNCIO DE DISPLAY DEL SLIDESHOW //
//********************************//
  function carousel() {  
      //diferenciaFun();
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
    } //recorrem tots els divs de slide i els aaguem

    slideIndex++;    

    /* si slideIndex es massa baix o massa alt, fem reset. Per ara no cal però conservo la iteració per si de cas.
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 1;
    } else if (slideIndex <= 0) {
      slideIndex = slides.length;
    } */

    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block"; // mostrem la slide que toca
    // show the relevant slide
      controlIndex(); //llancem la funcio per mantenir relació SLIDE a Nº resposta test

      //------- AQUÍ S'APLICA PER SI LA DIAPO PASSA SOLA
      cycle(true);  
  }

// FUNCIO DE CONTROL DEL CARRUSEL, QUAN HA DE PARAR I QUAN HA DE MODIFICAR L'INTERVAL DE TEMPS //
//********************************************************************************************//
 function cycle(r) {
     if (slideIndex<=1){r=false;} // primera diapo sense timer per tant CYCLE(false) 
     //la segona diapo es la del exemple A i segueix sense timer
      if (slideIndex==2){r=false;}
     if (slideIndex>=3){t=5000;} //  Primera pregunta del test: temps de 20 segons resposta 
     if (slideIndex===6) {r=false;} //exemple B del test, no timer, si no es exemple B, torna  CYCLE(true)
     if (slideIndex>=21){t=7000;} // després d'ultima pregunta amb temps 20, passem a temps de 30 segons resposta
     if (slideIndex>=34){r=false;} // stop temps exemples
     init= new Date(); // iniciem contador de temps transcorregut


    //console.log("cycle R bucle");


    if (r) { // si CYCLE(true) netejen i resetejem el setInterval 

     clearInterval(repeater); // netejen el timer
     repeater = setInterval(function() { // reiniciem el timer al carrusel
      carousel(); 
      }, t);} // amb el temps que tingui "t"

     else {
      clearInterval(repeater); //si CYCLE(false parem el timer)
    }}

//mostrem primera diapo al carregar la pàgina
  window.onload = function() {
    carousel();
  }; 

  carousel();
  cycle(true);

// control de canvi de diapo
  function plusDivs(n) {
    diferenciaFun(); // al passar a nou slide fem marca de temps final i restem final-inicial 
    cycle(true);
    slideIndex += n - 1;
    carousel();

  }

  function currentDiv(n) {
    cycle(true);
    slideIndex = n - 1;
    carousel();
  }

//  CONTROL DEL TEMPS TRANSCORREGUT ENTRE DIAPO I DIAPO, GURADAT EN ARRAY I AJUSTAT AL NUMERO DE RESPOSTA DEL TEST //
//*****************************************************************************************************************//
function diferenciaFun(){ // 
    finit= new Date();
    diferenciaT=finit-init;
    console.log("t: "+t+ "   array: "+ diferenciaT+ "  SI: "+si+"  No: "+no);
    if (t/1000 === diferenciaT){no++; checkultima();
                    console.log("SI: "+si+"\nNo: "+no);
                               }
    //array_diferenciaT.push("\n Input " + slideIndex + " Interval: " + diferenciaT/1000 );

    if (slideIndex ===2){
        array_diferenciaT.push("A",diferenciaT/1000);
    }

    if (slideIndex >=3 && slideIndex < 6){
        array_diferenciaT.push((slideIndex-2),diferenciaT/1000);
    }
    if (slideIndex ===6){
        array_diferenciaT.push("B",diferenciaT/1000 );
    }
    if (slideIndex >=7){
        array_diferenciaT.push((slideIndex-3), diferenciaT/1000 );
    }
}

function pillavalorArray(){

    console.log("array: "+array_diferenciaT);
    //console.log(array_diferenciaT.includes(1));  // comprobem si el valor es a l'array

}

//MARCA EL BUTTON AL PASSAR EL RATOLI PER SOBRE
function checkButton(element){element.checked = true;}
function uncheckButton(element){element.checked = false;}




// CONTROL DE RESPOSTES CORRECTES I INCORRECTES   //

function checkultima(){
    if (no===3){
        //Musica();
        alert("has acabat");
        currentDiv(slides.length-1); // <<-------------ENS PORTA A LA ULTIAM SLIDE QUE ES LA DELS RESULTATS TANT SI HEM FET TOTES LES DIAPOS COM SI N'HEM FALLAT 3 DE SEGUIDES


    }
    else {plusDivs(1);
        // console.log("SI: "+si+"\nNo: "+no);
         }
}

// FUNCIONS DE CONTROL DE RESPOSTES //
//*********************************//


function resta(){
no++;
    checkultima();
}
function suma(){
    si++;
    no=0;
    checkultima();
}
```

La dinámica del html es esta:

```
<div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 34</div>
        <img class ="imgtest" src="img/Bal1.png" >
                <table class="tableradio">  
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="radio" class="dot1" onClick="resta()" onmouseover="checkButton(this)" onmouseout="uncheckButton(this)"/> </td>
                            <td><input type="radio" class="dot1"  onClick="resta()" onmouseover="checkButton(this)" onmouseout="uncheckButton(this)"/> </td>
                            <td><input type="radio" class="dot1" onClick="suma()" onmouseover="checkButton(this)" onmouseout="uncheckButton(this)"/></td>
                            <td><input type="radio" class="dot1" onClick="resta()" onmouseover="checkButton(this)" onmouseout="uncheckButton(this)"/> </td>
                            <td><input type="radio" class="dot1" onClick="resta()" onmouseover="checkButton(this)" onmouseout="uncheckButton(this)"/></td>
                        </tr>
                            <tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>5</th></tr>
                </table>
  </div>
```

Botones con respuesta correcta y botones con respuesta incorrecta, ambas enlazan a "checkultima"

Pues eso, agradeceria mucho si alguien puede echarme una mano con esto.

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto, espero que le pueda servir a alguien:

```
function diferenciaFun(){ // 
finit= new Date();
diferenciaT=finit-init;
//console.log("t: "+t+ "  diferencia: "+ diferenciaT+ "  SI: "+si+"  No: "+no);

if(t>0){

if (diferenciaT>=t){no++; checkultima();
                console.log("SI: "+si+"\nNo: "+no);
                   } }
```